# Inline frame reloading the content again

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using jdev 11.1.2.2.0 .
I have one page which contains

```
<af:panelTabbed id="pt1">
<af:showDetailItem text="showDetailItem 1" id="sdi1" >
<af:inlineFrame id="if1" source="external application link"/>
</af:showDetailItem>
<af:showDetailItem text="showDetailItem 2" id="sdi2">
<af:outputText value="Welcome" id="ot1"/>
</af:showDetailItem>
</af:panelTabbed>
```

The external application has login page(page1).Once i login the application it is redirecting to some other page(page2), if i go to the second tab(showDetailItem 2) and come back again to the previous tab(showDetailItem 1) it is loading the first page(page1) for login again but my requirement is it should be in same page(page2).
Can anybody help me on this??